# How to have a handler for pagination complete

Tags: angular-ui-grid

This API from angular-ui-grid is provided for pagination

```
gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, vm.updateHeaderCheckBoxState)
vm.updateHeaderCheckBoxState = function() {
       const isAllVisibleRowsSubscribed = vm.isAllSelected(vm.gridOptions.titan.gridApi.grid.getVisibleRows());
       if (isAllVisibleRowsSubscribed) {
           $scope.headerCheckBoxSelected = true;
       } else {
           $scope.headerCheckBoxSelected = false;
       }
};
```

The registered handler using above API is called before the start of pagination. Do we have any alternative to handle after pagination ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating ui-grid Pagination, we do not have a handler for after pagination. The current event is used to load the data in case external pagination is enabled. So, the solution i worked out is remove ui-grid-selection directive, added a new column for checkboxes and went on with native implemenation.